# Do nonlinear constraints in fPortfolio Work?

Tags: r, optimization

I am trying to find a nonlinear portfolio optimizer

Within the fPortfolio documentation as well as Rmetrics Portfolio optimization with R/Rmetrics, it is possible to put in non linear constraints.

However after looking through the source code for the package, I have been unable to find anywhere where the non linear constraints are utilized.

Reproducible test code:

```
library(fPortfolio)
Data <- 100 * LPP2005.RET[,1:6]
Spec <- portfolioSpec()
setTargetReturn(Spec) <- mean(Data)
Constraints = 'maxW[1:6] = 0.5'
efficientPortfolio(Data, Spec, Constraints)

Title:
MV Efficient Portfolio 
Estimator:         covEstimator 
Solver:            solveRquadprog 
Optimize:          minRisk 
Constraints:       maxW 

Portfolio Weights:
SBI    SPI    SII    LMI    MPI    ALT 
0.0000 0.0086 0.2543 0.3358 0.0000 0.4013 
...
```

I add in a non linear constraint that cannot be satisfied. (The non linear function always returns 2 while I require that the value be between 0 and 1)

```
testfunc = function(x) 2
nonlinConstraints = c('listF=list(testfunc=testfunc)', 'minF = 0', 'maxF = 1')
newConstraints = c(Constraints, nonlinConstraints)
efficientPortfolio(Data, Spec, newConstraints)

    Title:
MV Efficient Portfolio 
Estimator:         covEstimator 
Solver:            solveRquadprog 
Optimize:          minRisk 
Constraints:       maxW 

Portfolio Weights:
SBI    SPI    SII    LMI    MPI    ALT 
0.0000 0.0086 0.2543 0.3358 0.0000 0.4013 
...
```

And get exactly the same answer.  Can someone who is familiar with the package tell me if I am doing something wrong or is the non linear constraints simply not implemented?

Answer (score 0):

You would see in `getAnywhere(.rquadprogArguments)` that `solveRquadprog` doesn't use `minFConstraints` or `maxFConstraints`.
You should call your own custom-made solver or use `solveRdonlp2`